# Is it possible to use Grover's algorithm for a real data search?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, quantum-computing

Last time I modeled the Grover search algorithm with Pyquil from Rigetti. It works on simulator. My question is, if it is possible to use this algorithm for a real search problem (yes I know, quantum computers still far apart from performance to do) in databases or files - theoretically, or is this algorithm only useable for the special search for a function result?

This is a theoretical question only.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend reading [this paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/pubs/jour/cise05-grov.pdf) for a discussion of practical applications of Grover's search, followed by the [appropriate tag](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grovers-algorithm) on Quantum Computing StackExchange. This question is asked so frequently, it makes more sense to keep track of good answers rather than writing a new one every time :-)